# ESX 6.7 VM not starting up after vmdk move

Tags: virtual-machines, vmware-esx

On one ESX, I have one VM with storage issues on a vmdk. So bad that the VM wouldn't start.

I had this error message :

```
2020-12-03T11:51:41.397Z| vmx| I125: [msg.hbacommon.outofspace] There is no more space for virtual disk 'setisrra-000001.vmdk'. You might be able to continue this session by freeing disk space on the relevant volume, and clicking _Retry. Click Cancel to terminate this session.
```

[image]

The size of the Datastore-Analytics is around 1,7 TB.
The size of the Datastore1 is around 500 GB.

So I thought I would move the "setissra-000001.vmdk" which was taking up space from one Datastore to another.

I shut down my VM, made a snapshot (the second one since its creation).
And I moved the "setissra-000001.vmdk" (note : "copy" wouldn't work).

The move was made, but now "setissra-000001.vmdk" is 80GB instead of 15,9 for some reason.
And now I can't power on the VM it says : "unable to enumerate all disks".

I don't know what to do? I'd like to avoid full reinstallation.

Thanks

Comment: Did you move only a single vmdk file without the rest of the VM?

Comment: Did you ssh into the host and move files around with 'mv' etc.?

Comment: I moved a single file, and I didn't use ssh - i did it on the web gui of the ESX

Comment: Try moving the file back and power on the VM. Before moving the VMDK, merge the snapshots. And try to move it again. Before moving, do not forget to make backups.

Answer (score 2):

the .vmx files contains paths to the .vmdk files. they need to be correct for the VM to run. Additionally, it looks like you had a snapshot on the VM, which splits the .vmdk in multiple files. You could try to move the rest of the VM to the other datastore, and the paths should be correct again (you might to unregister and reregister the VM). If that doesn't work you might need to revert all your changes, or restore the backups of your VM.

Regarding the larger file size: Your .vmdk was Thin provisioned, that was lost during the move of the file, so now it occupies the size of the whole virtual disk.